# How to mask points below the line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was practicing with matplotlib.pyplot and getting used with masking data (np.ma.masked_where) point.  Is there any math formula or way to mask data points below the line? Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
points_X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] // your points_X data
points_Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] // your points_Y data

new_points_X=[]
new_points_Y=[]

for i in range(len(points_X)):
    if(points_Y[i] <= points_X[i]):
        new_points_Y.append(points_Y[i])
        new_points_X.append(points_X[i])

plot(new_points_X, new_points_Y)
```

Comment: If you show how your data point is organized I can help you more

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check if the y-values are lower than the linear function of your x-values.
In your case it seems to be angle bisector of the first quadrant, so offset is `0` and slope is `1`:

```
y < x
```

In general check for

```
y < m * x + t    # with slope m and offset t
```

I.e. in your case simply

```
y.mask = y < x
plt.plot(x, y)
```

---

*Example:*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
np.random.seed(7)                                   # prepare data
x = np.random.random(10)     
y = np.random.random(10)
y = np.ma.masked_array(y)

# plot all values 
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', ms=10, mec='k', mfc=(0,0,0,0), label = 'all points')  

y.mask = y < x                                      # mask values below angular bisector
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label = '$y \geq x$')          # plot masked array
plt.plot((0, 1), (0, 1), 'b')                       # plot angular bisector


m = 3                                               # prepare the general case
t = -1
y.mask = y < m * x + t                              # mask values below linear function
plt.plot(x, y, 'rx', label = '$y \geq 3x - 1$')     # plot masked array
plt.plot((0, 1), (m*0+t, m*1+t), 'r')               # plot linear function

plt.ylim(0, 1)
fig.legend(ncol=3, loc='upper center')
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate for your detail answer, mate

Comment: @ChauLoi You're welcome - and may I ask, why you then accepted the more complicated answer which needs a loop and a full copy of all x- and y-values which shall be visible instead of a simple one liner? I thought you were searching for sth based on numpy's masked arrays?

Comment: @SpghttCd. Sorry for late reply mate. Btw, I am just a beginner. I learnt from books ans examples. I incline to inherit it meanwhile, you are more advanced with more experiences, therefore, You know which method is easy and readable. You may find it silly but this mere question opened my mind.